# gorename: What is a 'DO NOT EDIT' marker?

Tags: go

I'm using vscode and trying to rename a variable name.

It fails saying:

```
Rename failed: gorename: cannot rename identifiers in generated file containing DO NOT EDIT marker: /home/adam/go/src/hello/hello.go
```

So what is a DO NOT EDIT marker? Why is it there and how can I remove it so that gorename can do its thing?

This is how my file begins:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "c/greet.h"
import "C"
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the source code for `gorename`](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/refactor/rename/spec.go#L574-L593), the check is simple: It looks for a comment at the beginning of the line that contains the phrase "DO NOT EDIT":

```
// Matches cgo generated comment as well as the proposed standard:
//  https://golang.org/s/generatedcode
var generatedRx = regexp.MustCompile(`// .*DO NOT EDIT\.?`)

// generated reports whether ast.File is a generated file.
func generated(f *ast.File, tokenFile *token.File) bool {

    // Iterate over the comments in the file
    for _, commentGroup := range f.Comments {
        for _, comment := range commentGroup.List {
            if matched := generatedRx.MatchString(comment.Text); matched {
                // Check if comment is at the beginning of the line in source
                if pos := tokenFile.Position(comment.Slash); pos.Column == 1 {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Reading [elsewhere in the source code](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/refactor/rename/rename.go#L487-L499), where the error message itself is generated, it looks like the error message may simply be misleading:

```
// Renaming not supported if cgo files are affected.
var generatedFileNames []string
for _, info := range r.packages {
    for _, f := range info.Files {
        tokenFile := r.iprog.Fset.File(f.Pos())
        if filesToUpdate[tokenFile] && generated(f, tokenFile) {
            generatedFileNames = append(generatedFileNames, tokenFile.Name())
        }
    }
}
if !Force && len(generatedFileNames) > 0 {
    return fmt.Errorf("refusing to modify generated file%s containing DO NOT EDIT marker: %v", plural(len(generatedFileNames)), generatedFileNames)
}
```

I see you are using CGO. It appears that this also triggers the "generated file" marker.

Comment: Yes when I removed the CGO parts the error disappeared. So yeah it's a bug. Thanks.